# Failed to connect to firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/:::443

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, crashlytics

I am trying to add firebase crashlytics and analytics in my flutter application:
I followed the steps properly as mentioned in documentation, This is my main function:

```dart
void main() async {
  // ensure flutter binding before accessing any resources
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // ... other pieces of code

  // initialize firebase to use firebase services including crashlytics
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  // send crash logs to firebase crashlytics
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
  }; // this statement will pass all the crashes caught by flutter to firebase
  // FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;

  // In case there are errors uncaught by flutter framework
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };

  // set device orientation to Portrait Up
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  // return top level widget to be showed
  runApp(const GlobalWrapperWidget());
}
```

But i am getting this log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
D/FlutterGeolocator( 6132): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator( 6132): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 6132): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 6132): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator( 6132): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator( 6132): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65259/bYd3Url-4_Y=/ws
Syncing files to device Redmi Note 7 Pro...
D/SessionsDependencies( 6132): Dependency to CRASHLYTICS added.
I/FirebaseApp( 6132): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
D/FirebaseSessions( 6132): Initializing Firebase Sessions SDK.
I/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132): Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.6.0 for com.jbullsinfotech.flutter_template
D/SessionsDependencies( 6132): Subscriber CRASHLYTICS registered.
D/SessionConfigFetcher( 6132): Fetching settings from server.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 6132): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/DpmTcmClient( 6132): RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0
E/SessionConfigFetcher( 6132): Error failing to fetch the remote configs: Failed to connect to firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/:::443
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132): Settings request failed.
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132): java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/:::443
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpGetRequest.execute(HttpGetRequest.java:78)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:112)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:200)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:193)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzo.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:67)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/FirebaseCrashlytics( 6132): No version control information found
D/LifecycleServiceBinder( 6132): Binding service to application.
D/SessionLifecycleService( 6132): Service bound to new client on process 6132
D/SessionLifecycleService( 6132): App has not yet foregrounded. Using previously stored session: null
D/SessionLifecycleService( 6132): Client android.os.Messenger@c95f65d bound at 420994367. Clients: 1
D/SessionLifecycleClient( 6132): Connected to SessionLifecycleService. Queue size 0
```

## this is the log I get when I explicitely throw an exception:

E/FirebaseCrashlytics( 9191): Cannot send reports. Timed out while fetching settings.
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend( 9191): Making request to: https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend( 9191): Status Code: 200

I sincerely don't understand what to do. Looked into similar questions on stackoverflow and github but none solved the issue here.

Comment: When you say that you have tried some solutions, what have you try? just asking to avoid sharing the same info.  On a first look, it looks like a network related issue and not something specific to the SDK configuration. Are you using a proxy? or firewall?  Does the app have internet access?

Comment: No proxy, Using wifi. also tried on mobile network. added native code. for android and ios. reset the app and reinstalled it. cleared studio build and then rebuilt it. and some other stuff, even i don't remember what